# Discord bot repeats word until commanded to stop in Python?

Tags: python, while-loop, discord, boolean, bots

Can someone explain to me why this does not stop the while loop when I type '!stop'

```
stop_var = False
if message.content.startswith('!stop'):
  stop_var = True

if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
  stop_var = False
  while (stop_var == False):
      await message.channel.send("Hello")
      await asyncio.sleep(1)
      if stop_var:
        break
```

Comment: Is this in some kind of handler function that gets called whenever a new message arrives? In this case `stop_var` is a local variable and just because you set `stop_var` to stop in one invocation of the function does not mean it is set in another invocation of the handler function.

Comment: There may not be a spot in the execution cycle for the stop command to run. Attaching a debugger/logging will help. 

You may also have a threading issue

Comment: @iamsimonsmale can you explain more please? Thanks.

Comment: @Mushroomator so what should I do instead

Comment: Probably read about [asynchronous programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony_(computer_programming)) as you're using [async.io](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html). You should understand the concept otherwise you won't understand the problem. It's impossible to explain those kind of things in a comment and comments are certainly not made for this.

Comment: Please avoid posting the same question 3 times in 2 days

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs Thanks for the help, but my question was not answered in enough detail the other times. Also this time I gave code and asked why it did not work so it's different.

Comment: you may try to use `global` variable because at this moment you use local variable - and when you run the same function two times then every execution use own variable with own value - and one execution can't change value in other execution.